# File operations on FTPS server with cURL

Tags: windows, download, curl, upload, ftps

I need to perform some file transfer operations on some remote FTPS server that uses certificate authentication from a Windows 2008 scripting environment, so that's why I'm stuck with cURL pretty much.

I've downloaded cURL x64 version for Windows - 7.33.0 from:
http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/

I connect to the server like so:

```
curl --cert mycert.crt --key mykey.key -k -v -u user:pass ftp://IP:990/ --ftp-ssl
```

The FTPS server structure is this:

```
/homedir

 pyr_<ID> 
    - archives
    - commun
    - in 
    - out

 pyr_<ID2>
    - archives
    - commun
    - in 
    - out

 pyr_<ID3>
    - archives
    - commun
    - in 
    - out

...
```

My tasks are to:

- Move files which match a wildcard: filename*.csv from all /pyr_*/out folders to a local folder.
- Copy all filename_ID*.csv files from a local folder to the FTPS server in their respective /pyr_ID/in folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the utility MOVEit Freely to be suitable for my needs.
Hope it can help others looking for a solution.